# How to use 'unique' to create labels for a Shiny input?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to define the input labels for 'selectInput' without specifying each one but using 'unique' gives:

```
 Error in (function (choice, name)  : 
      All sub-lists in "choices" must be named.
```

Sample code:

```
  m <- sample(c('CT', 'MRI', 'US', 'XRAY'), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
    ui <- fluidPage( 
       titlePanel("Rad Data"),
       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           selectInput(inputId = 'modality', label = "Modality", choices = list(unique(m), selected = 'CT', selectize = FALSE))   
         ),
         mainPanel(outputPlot(outputId = 'distPlot'))
       ))
```

Thanks for any advice.
rms

Comment: Is "m" predefined or do you want to dynamically generate it from your data?

Comment: Yes, m is a data frame variable. The unique factors are usually the 4 I sampled from but sometimes a different one is added or one is removed and it would be elegant if I don't need to edit the selectInput choices.

Comment: Then I think that a reactive UI is what you're after, covered by Kristoffer's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to have the items in the selectInput to be unique. In your example you have too many lists (`m` is a list and you encapsulate it in another list in `choices = list(...`.

Try this:

```
m <- sample(c('CT', 'MRI', 'US', 'XRAY'), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage( 
    titlePanel("Rad Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = 'modality', label = "Modality", choices = unique(m), selected = 'CT', selectize = FALSE)   
      ),
      mainPanel()
  )),    
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

**Update:** if you want to generate the choices based on a column in a data.frame you could use uiOutput and renderUI as originally suggested by  A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1:

```
df <- data.frame(m = sample(c('CT', 'MRI', 'US', 'XRAY'), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage( 
    titlePanel("Rad Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("unique_modalities")
      ),
      mainPanel()
  )),    
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$unique_modalities <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = 'modality', label = "Modality", choices = unique(df$m), selected = 'CT', selectize = FALSE)   
    })
  }
)
```